# QGIS Attribute overlay?

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I'm creating a video with the Time Manager Plugin in QGIS 3.11.

How do I draw data from an attribute for a tugboats engine power in a static location on the screen?

As it is it currently follows the boat as it moves along with the ship.  Once I start integrating more vessels it's going to get confusing doing it this way though.  Would prefer the data just display on the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: It looks like the time manager plugin can handle multiple layers. Try adding a polygon layer (styled with no fill) that covers the entire extent of the screen. Add a timestamp to this layer, and use the same polygon at every time stamp. Hopefully this will keep the screen stationary while the tugboat features moves.